# Using scala-meta to annotate a case class

Tags: scala, scalameta

I have a real beginners question using scala-meta

I want to add annotations to a subset of a case class’s fields based on the name of the the field.
The classes and fields to annotate are defined  as follows:

```
val classMapping = Map[String,String](
    ("com.example.employees","""OntologyContext("http://schema.org")"""),
    ("Employee.scala","""OntologyType("person")""")
)

val fieldMapping = Map[String,String](
    ("hello","""OntologyRef("name")"""),
    ("job","""OntologyRef("title")"""),("id","""Obfuscated""")
)
```

Before:

```
package com.example.employees
import java.time.LocalDate
case class Employee(
  hello: String,
  job:String,
  id:String,
  employmentDate: Date)
```

After:

```
package com.example.employees
import java.time.LocalDate
@OntologyContext(“http://schema.org”)
@OntologyType(“person”)
case class Employee(
  @OntologyRef(“name”) hello: String,
  @OntologyRef(“title”) job: String,
  @Obfuscated() id:String,
  employmentDate: Date
)
```

My question pertains to the syntax of the quasiquotes that are needed in the transform of the tree:

1. selecting the indicated field; and
2. inserting the annotations

Can you refer me to any examples that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, this is not currently possible. Scala-meta annotation macros do not support parameters yet https://github.com/scalameta/paradise/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

[Now it's supported](https://github.com/scalameta/paradise) with scala.meta 1.1.0 and macro paradise 3.0.0-M5

Still having problems with named parameters

Answer (score -1):

Note: the latest [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2016/11/11/intellij-idea-2016-3-rc-scala-js-scala-meta-and-more/) (Dec. 2016) should help using those quasiquotes, since they are now supported:

> Another major plugin improvement is the support for [scala.meta](http://scalameta.org/) – the new metaprogramming toolkit designed to succeed `scala.reflect`.
>   IntelliJ IDEA supports new-style macro annotations and provides coding assistance for `scala.meta` quasiquotes.

[image: https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/scala/files/2016/11/image00.png]

> The new plugin version brings you gutter icons for `scala.meta` macro annotations. Clicking these icons expands the corresponding annotations.
>   IntelliJ IDEA automatically detects when annotations change and prompts you to recompile them via the gutter icon (or the standard Recompile action.)